# Bridge networking for KVM in 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, kvm-virtualization, network-bridge

I am trying to set up bridged networking for a KVM guest. My guest OS (Windows 10) is set up to use br0 but has no network connection. My host gets it's IP address via DHCP (the router always hands it the same reserved IP). I want my VM guests to also get an IP address via DHCP. What am I doing wrong?
Instructions I've found on the web aren't helping me because they don't address which networking subsystems they assume I am using and it appears networking is managed by some combination of NetworkManager, networkd, netplan, and/or /etc/network/interfaces many of which are incompatible and conflict with each other.

Here are some details: (I added br0. virbr0 and virbr0-nic must have been added when I installed virtlib)

```
vmhost:#
vmhost:# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
vmhost:#
vmhost:# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:52:82:62:df:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.170.20.80/24 brd 192.170.20.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eno1
       valid_lft 85298sec preferred_lft 85298sec
    inet6 fe80::2093:3ece:58e4:26cd/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:18:91:70 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:18:91:70 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
10: br0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether da:f0:24:4f:23:85 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
vmhost:#
vmhost:# cat /etc/network/interfaces 
# ifupdown has been replaced by netplan(5) on this system.  See
# /etc/netplan for current configuration.
# To re-enable ifupdown on this system, you can run:
#    sudo apt install ifupdown
vmhost:#
vmhost:# cat /etc/netplan/vmhost.yaml 
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces: [ eno1 ]
      accept-ra: no
vmhost:#
vmhost:#
```

Comment: Isn't that just the common case as shown at the examples for netplan https://netplan.io/examples#configuring-network-bridges  ?

Comment: @Christian: Yes, I would think mine is just the common case. So someone please help me debug why I have no network connectivity from my guest using br0. I have tried replacing 'renderer: NetworkManager' with 'renderer: networkd' but that didn't help

Comment: lets check one by one what networkd should have done - was eno1 bridged to it (check with `brctl show br0`) and if that is ok does I think `dhclient br0` resolve an IP for you? Also I wonder why your eno1 still has an IP, it should have let it go due to the config - or have you set a static IP on eno1 as well somehow?

Comment: Thank you! I went step by step making sure each thing was assigned as it should be and I got it working! netplan -apply wasn't enough on its own, I had to reboot to finally get it working (with networkd, not NetworkManager)